# Having an Issue Rendering Where it just renders a wierd image

Tags: rendering

Recently i have tried my hand at blender and when i went to render a image it was this very messed up looking render, this is what the camera says its showing but when i go to render it shows this other render that is completely messed up and looks nothing like it does in blender. in both cycles and eevee

[image: Full Cycles Render]
[image: Full Eevee Render]
[image: Taken From in Scene]

Comment: Could be objects in the outliner disabled for viewport but enabled for render (camera icon)